# Validation Rules on Conversion

Tags: lead-conversion

I'm trying to ensure that there is atleast some activity on a lead before it is converted. I've tried setting a validation rule

```
ISCONVERTED && ISBLANK(LASTACTIVITYDATE)
```

but it returns as a validation error regardless of if the date is populated or not

Even if I try without the converted check the rule works just on saving but fails on conversion.

Please help

Answer (score 2):

As per the description of LastActivityDate from salesforce documentation:

*Value is one of the following, whichever is the most recent:
Due date of the most recent event logged against the record.
Due date of the most recently closed task associated with the record.*

I believe what is happening is that the LastActivityDate is emptied everytime a lead is converted. On conversion, the activities created on the lead previously are transferred to the contact created on lead conversion. 
Hence everytime you convert a lead, it does not have any related tasks anymore and the LastActivityDate is set to null. I checked the value of the LastActivityDate for a converted lead from the back end before and after conversion.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug if you ask me.

Queried from my org (Id values redacted to protect the innocent):

```
SELECT Id, LastActivityDate FROM Lead WHERE Id = '00QXXXXXXXXXXXX'
```

Output:

```
Id               LastActivityDate
00QXXXXXXXXXXXX  2016-04-04
```

Attempting to convert puts this in my debug logs (maximum logging):

```
13:10:14.289 (2715429390)|VALIDATION_RULE|03dXXXXXXXXXXXX|ConvertOnlyWithActivity
13:10:14.289 (2715509591)|VALIDATION_FORMULA|IsNull(LastActivityDate)|LastActivityDate=null
13:10:14.289 (2715518831)|VALIDATION_FAIL
```

As you can see, the conversion is telling me that LastActivityDate is null when it's clearly not.

You should contact support, verify the behavior, and get a bug logged.

Comment: isn't this because the activities are deleted first (transferred to contact) when converting?

Comment: @Fred That's what I thought, too, but I found an old post from 2012 where someone used a nearly identical formula (using LastActivityDate to block lead conversion without activity), and it was apparently working then. Either way, I think we need to have salesforce.com verify if this is the intended behavior. The last I recall, task triggers ran sometime after lead validation rules occurred, so there *should* be a LastActivityDate at the point where the validation rules run.

Comment: Can you folks confirm if this is a bug? Or should I go ahead and contact Support?

Answer (score 0):

> If you are converting Leads and you wanted to enforce the Validation
>   Rule, you need to enable "Require validation for Converted Leads"
>   [from here](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000176187)
>
> To enable the "Require validation for Converted Leads"

- Go to your Name | Set-up | Customize | Leads | Settings
- Enable
- "Require validation for Converted Leads" Click on Save.

Also, try this `ISCONVERTED &&`**ISNULL**`(LASTACTIVITYDATE)`